# Send information of submit button on php get_file_contents post

Tags: php, html, web

I have a page. I need to get the contents of on my own page. The peculiar thing is that the page returns the correct information only when the value of the submit button is kept as it is. So when I make a form as

```
<form action="http://mydestinationpage.php" method="POST">
    <input name="rid" type="TEXT"><br>
    <input name="submit" type="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

the correct result is returned. But when I manually send a post data with `"rid"` as my query, the correct data is not retrieved. So my question is, how do I get the file contents through php using the above form as it is.

```
<?php
$query = $_GET['query'];
$postdata = http_build_query(array(
    'rid' => $query
));

$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context = stream_context_create($opts);
echo file_get_contents('mydestinationpage.php', false, $context);  
?>
```

This is how I tried to do it and it doesn't give the desired result.

Comment: without the php code, we can't help you.

Comment: please show how you are "manually" sending a post data with rid...

Comment: supposing the destination page has some mechanism of checking whether or not the form was submitted as it is (i don't know if that's possible). Can I send the request header in such a way through php so as to trick the destination page into thinking the correct form was submitted?

Comment: <?php
$query=$_GET['query'];
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'rid' => $query
    )
);

$opts = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
echo file_get_contents("mydestinationpage.php",false,$context);
?>  this is how i tried to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the submit name and value into your POST Data Array.

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'rid' => $query,
        'submit' => ''
    )
);
```

I am guessing that maybe the destination script is looking for $_POST['submit'] and maybe a value.

Comment: I modified the code a bit.

    $postdata = http_build_query(
        array(
            'rid' => $query,
            'submit' => ' "submit'' '
        )
    );

and it worked. Thank you